ADF Pipelines performance i particular Web activity
Web activities in a ADF Pipeline are taking over 15 seconds when the same HTTPS call outside of ADF maxes at 200 ms.
What is eating up the extra time?  The responses are minimal (max 2 kb) and the requests are constrained to the URL plus tops 2 headers.
Also can Monitoring be disabled?  Monitoring yields the same information as Debug and has to be stored (which must come at a cost).  If I want to track something I can do a Web Activity to Insights.

Can you explain your ask with an example? and what is information exactly that you need to monitor in the logs?

Run any pipeline in a standard factory and monitoring is done automatically. I want that off since it has to eat time and storage. Don’t need an example for that question.
